# Workflow to send email with selected picklist value

Tags: workflow

The criteria are to create a workflow rule when Status (Picklist field) change to value (Delivered ) and ( Confirmed) then the email will be set and for which I am using email alert.

below is the rule criteria:

```
AND(ISCHANGED(KNDY4__Status__c ) , 
OR( ISPICKVAL(KNDY4__Status__c ,'delivered '), 
ISPICKVAL(KNDY4__Status__c, 'confirmed') ))
```

I test this and email alert only works when i change status to confirmed but not with delivered .

Do let me know is this correct or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You can see , there is trailing space in your formula after delivered string.

```
OR( ISPICKVAL(KNDY4__Status__c ,'delivered '),
```

Just remove that space

```
OR( ISPICKVAL(KNDY4__Status__c ,'delivered'),
```